# How to make sure that mysqldump command is working in command prompt

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\IT-Admin>mysqldump
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Where is the mysqldump executable file? It needs to be in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 2):

So just as dwjv suggested, set the PATH OS system environmental variable to include the path on the OS where the mysqldump.exe exists (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm); otherwise, change the directory in your command window to that path where it is and then run the command.

1. Add the full path (example`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump\`) where the mysqldump.exe is located to the environmental system variable of the OS where you're running this.
2. Example:`C:\Users\IT-Admin>CD /D "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump"` and then press enter to get this in the command window where you'd type *'mysqldump'* as shown here `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump>mysqldump` and then press enter.
3. Furthermore, you could put the full path to the mysqldump.exe in with double quotes around it and then press enter as well e.g. `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump"` and then press enter.

So there are three potential solutions for you!

Answer (score -1):

Please add `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` to this path at your user variables and system variables; if you are using a wamp server, add `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin` to this path at your user variables and system variables.

**Note: MySQL version path will change as per your installation**